# Windows Azure Remote Desktop Can't Connect

Tags: azure

I followed all the steps on the links below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2010/12/29/azure-home-part-13-remote-desktop-configuration.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/enriquelima/archive/2011/03/30/deploying-an-rdp-enabled-azure-package-outside-of-visual-studio.aspx

Also, successfully enabled the RDP as azure portal showed me:

*"Successfully configured Remote Desktop for cloud service BLABLAServer"*

but when I try to connect to any of the running web role Remote Desktop connection error pops up:

"remote deskop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1. RDP not enabled.
2. Turned off.
3. Remote computer is not available on the network."

could someone help me what else I need to do?

I also installed the certificate on local machine.

Comment: For those coming in via Google. I had this problem and it was because my ACL was set to an IP range that my computer no longer fell into. A dumb reason, but might trip someone else up too :)

Answer (score 2):

Had the problem and I solved it by flushing my dns.

1. Open command prompt and type: 
   ipconfig /flushdns

Answer (score 1):

I get that sometimes when I try to access the downloaded file directly from my browser's download bar. The workaround is to save the .rdp file, then go to the folder you downloaded it, edit the file and make sure that the "Ask for credentials" is checked. Save it and try reopening it.

Comment: Thank you, the error I was getting was "User Does Not Exist" which made no sense to me because I am the one that entered the credentials for the upload. +1 because this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but it only occurred when I was trying to access the remote desktop through our firewall.